# Get approved FROM or BY

Tags: grammar

I need to ask my colleague to get the approval from his manager for something to process further.. Which of the below sentences are appropriate in this scenario?

1. Please get the approval from Donald to proceed.
2. Please get this request approved *from* Donald to proceed.
3. Please get this request approved *by* Donald to proceed.

Comment: “We need approval from Donald”. *To proceed* seems to be superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **get (approval)** -> **from**

"Get" in this context requires "from", same as in:

> **Get** the book **from** the shelf.

---

> **(to) approve** -> **by**

"(To) approve" is a verb and requires "by".

---

Therefore 1 and 3 are correct, 2 is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

***Approval*** is a **noun**. Think of it like a physical object that you have to obtain by asking someone for it. If you needed Bob to give you a book, you would say:

> I need to get the book **from** Bob.

Just the same for approval, for all that it is not generally a physical object:

> I need to get approval **from** Bob.

***Approved*** is the past tense/past participle of the **verb** *to approve*, and you want to say who is doing something. That uses the preposition by to indicate the actor:

> I need to get it approved **by** Bob.

The essence of the difference is that one is a verb, and the other is a noun. This means that *get* is a different sense in each case - one is in the sense of *to obtain*, and the other is the sense of *to cause*.

Comment: look at your first example more carefully: "from" is not related to "approval", but to "get". And that is already my answer  - I made the same mistake in the first version of my answer:D

Comment: @virolino the issue of the difference between the two is ultimately that one is a verb and the other is a noun - hence the different sense of "get" in each. Clarified in answer.

Comment: Your point is correct, but only partially. As I said, please read your first example: there is no "approval", but there is "from". The change approval <-> approved makes the next word (from / by) relate to different entities (both of the entities being verbs: get and approved).